# Calculating center of mass integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics, trigonometric-integrals

I have a few problems with the calculation of the center of mass of this curve,

[image]

Can someone explain me the first two steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of this curve is the quarter of  circle perimeter $$=\frac {2\pi R}{4}=\frac {\pi R}{2} $$

mass=density x length.
$$M=\rho .\frac {\pi R}{2} $$

the abscisse of a point $M $ in the curve is

$$x=R\cos (\theta )$$

where $\theta $ is the angle $(\vec{Ox},\vec {OM}) $.

For $y_G $, you will have
$$\frac {1}{M}\int_0^R \rho R\sin (\theta)Rd\theta $$

Comment: if $x = Rcos(\theta) $ then $\frac_{dx}{d\theta} = -Rsin(\theta) $ and $ dx = -Rsin(\theta)d\theta $? Isnt it?

Comment: @AyoubRossi I calculate y_G.